# Regex pattern code in java to get substring between $....$

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a string like RULE_ID_$TEST$.VALUE

How to get TEST which is in between for $.$ using regex in java,

I am new to this regex, i know how to use substring but not regex pattern

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "RULE_ID_$TEST$.VALUE";
String result = s.split("$")[1];
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this question, which was how to do it using regex